# Possible reasons why status report page is blank

Tags: log-messages

I'm using Drupal 7.23 on my test site and since a couple of days the status report page is completely blank (no theme, no menu, nothing). No info shown at all. Other (report) pages are shown without noticeable issues.

Does anybody have an idea what could cause this?
I have a almost similar 7.23 life site that shows this /admin/reports/status report perfectly.

Any log-file to check?

Comment: Have you cleared your caches?

Comment: usually this suggests a php error somewhere, so I'd take a look in your server's php_error logs

Comment: Clearing cache didn't help. Next challenge for me is to find the php_error logs. Im working on a VPS based on CentOS 6. I found related questions from others on the internet, but the locations mentioned are not the one the php_error file can be found by me. I'm familiar with Unix/Linux commands but not with the variables or locations PHP could be installed.

Comment: In the possible duplicate reference, the locations /var/log/apache2 is mentioned, but I have no apache* folder in that location, so not applicable for CentOS 6. I have DirectAdmin running, but also in the possible logs no Apache log shown. Httpd log is not the same isn't it?

Comment: @Jimajamma Could it be that the error_log file is not enabled? I did a "locate php.ini" and it showed me that it was in /usr/local/lib/php.ini . When doing a grep for error_log in this *ini it showed: `; server-specific log, STDERR, or a location specified by the error_log
; Set maximum length of log_errors. In error_log information about the source is
;error_log = php_errors.log
;error_log = syslog`

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to get the php logging, but I do know now why this report page was blank. I had installed a not complete functioning module named Backup and Migrate Opencloud that needed Libraries 7.x-2.0 or higher. I was still on 7.x-1.0. After I updated to the latest libraries version the status report page showed up again.